# Failed to complete request: java.io.IOException: Stream closed from Spring boot Controller method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsonb, jsonb-api

I am using jsonb as a preferred json mapper for spring boot. But I am getting a Stream closed exception when calling the controller via a Rest Client (Soap UI). If I use Jackson as a preferred json mapper, everything works smoothly. I am using Spring WebMVC. No JAX-RS. We are trying to use the standard Json API for the Java Platform. The returned object is a simple POJO annotated with lombok annotations (@Data). Other uses for the jsonb implementation is working when in other non spring-mvc methods.

The code/config pieces:

1) pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

2) application.yaml:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: spring-boot-jsonb-sample
    profiles:
        active: local
    http:
        converters:
            preferred-json-mapper: jsonb
```

3) Controller method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/resource", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Response method(@RequestBody @NotNull @Valid Request request) {
   return service.serviceMethod(request);
}
```

Exception:

```
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.java:130) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:225) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at
......

ERROR 18020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.java:130) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:225) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at
```

I tried switching servers: Jetty/Tomcat. I also tried different implementations: Apache Johnzon vs Eclipse Yasson.

Comment: please dont "explain" what your code does, show us the code, its impossible to know whats wrong without seeing the code!

Comment: I added the code that is failing.

Comment: @Abdul, I'm facing the same problems. did you get it solved?

Comment: The only way I was able to get rid of the exception is to set the value of the **spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper** property to **jackson**.

Comment: Still not fixed in newest Spring version.

Answer (score 0):

This also affects Spring Boot 2.2.5 with the latest version of Yasson, 1.0.6.

It is a bug between Yasson and Spring Boot. It's being solved on Yasson's side, in this issue https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/389